# Cannot add Domain Users to SQLServer security

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sql-server-2008

I installed a win2008 server (WSQL)
Its has successfully joined another Win2008 server which is the domain controller.

Now back to WSQL machine, I connect it to the domain... And I install SqlServer-2008 on it.

The install works fine.

Now, I want all the domain users to be able to log on my brand new database.
But in "Security", I cannot find out the "Domain Users", or any domains, at all !?

Got the feeling, I missed something...

**update**
Sounds like an issue with service account when I installed SqlServer...

Comment: See if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server

Comment: Yes, I've seen, but it doesn't work, same results...

Comment: Do you mean you cannot see your Active Directory domain when clicking the "Locations..." button ?

Comment: Ok, now If I change "Locations..." to my domain, I can see the "Domain" groups, but If I pick up, "Domain Users", I get WSQL\None in the "Login name" !?

Comment: All the other "Domain ..." send me an error message : "Error 15401, Windows NT user or group xxx not found" !